# Prove that either $a+b+c=0$ or $a=b=c$ for the given conditions. (INMO 2000)

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, ratio

> If $a,b,c,x$ are real numbers, such that $abc\ne 0$ and :
> $$\dfrac{xb+(1-x)c}{a}=\dfrac{xc+(1-x)a}{b}=\dfrac{xa+(1-x)b}{c}$$
> then prove that either $a+b+c=0$ or $a=b=c$

***My Approach:***

$$\dfrac{xb+(1-x)c}{a}=\dfrac{xc+(1-x)a}{b}=\dfrac{xa+(1-x)b}{c}=k\ \text{(suppose)}$$

assuming $a+b+c\ne 0$:

$$k=\dfrac{xb+(1-x)c+xc+(1-x)a+xa+(1-x)b}{a+b+c}=1$$
$$\text{Thus}\ x=\dfrac{a-c}{b-c}=\dfrac{b-a}{c-a}=\dfrac{c-b}{a-b}$$

From the first two equalities, we have $(a-c)^2=(b-a)(c-b)\Rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca$

$a(a-c)+b(b-a)+c(c-b)=0\Rightarrow (a-c)(a-bx-cx)=0$

Either $a=c$ and since the function is symmetric, $a=b=c$, or $x=\dfrac{a}{b+c}$

Suppose $x=\dfrac{a}{b+c}$, since the function is symmetric:

$$x=\dfrac{a}{b+c}=\dfrac{b}{c+a}=\dfrac{c}{a+b}=\dfrac{1}{2}\Rightarrow 2a=b+c$$

Now $2a=b+c\ \text{and}\ 2b=c+a \Rightarrow 2(a+b)=(a+b)+2c\Rightarrow b=2c-a\Rightarrow 2c-a=c-2a\Rightarrow a=c$

Thus $x=\dfrac{a}{b+c}$ again gives $a=b=c$

How can I find the case $a+b+c=0$. Please check my approach and give suggestions as to what I must add to my approach to make it better and find the missing solution.

***THANKS***

Comment: The second step, where the denominator was $a+b+c$. That case will need to be considered separately. However if the rest of the proof is correct not much needs to be amended, apart from a remark "if $a+b+c \ne0$".

Comment: @player3236, Yes I get it now!!!! Thanks, but would you please suggest as to how can we prove that $a+b+c=0$ is a solution?

Comment: Logically/technically there is no need to? Would a substitution of $c= -a-b$ do the trick? Edit: it probably wouldn't.

Comment: @player3236 You are not required to prove that there is a solution set with $a+b+c = 0 $. Your approach is fine (but the phrasing could be made clearer). IE I would write it as " If $a +b + c = 0$, then the condition in the question is satisfied. Else, ... (we will show that $a=b=c$)."